# Python FPDP multi_cell just returns a blank

Tags: python, fpdf

I am using the `multi_cell()` function from FPDF in Python.

However every time I call it I just get a blank space where the cell should be. If however I call `cell()` it displays the cell.

#### Code

See two examples below.

1. Blank space with:

```py
pdf.multi_cell(25,cell_height,ticket_no,1,0,"J",1)
```

2. Cell populated with data with

```py
pdf.cell(25,cell_height,ticket_no,1,0,"L",1)
```

Anyone got an idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PyFPDF, then `cell()` and `multi_cell()` take different parameters:

Cell:

- https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/Cell
- https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/source/browse/fpdf/fpdf.py#704

MultiCell:

- https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/wiki/MultiCell
- https://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/source/browse/fpdf/fpdf.py#797

Multi_cell doesn't take `ln`, so by keeping that in, you end up shifting some of the parameters right by one, and saying:

```
align=0, fill="J"
```

instead of

```
align="J", fill=1
```